# Язык по умолчанию Expo cli ios

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile-development, apple, expo

Написали приложение, но модераторы эпл отклонили его ссылаясь на то что в системном диалоге часть текста на английском языке. Приложение написано на русском, на диалоговое окно повлиять в вызываемом методе на язык нельзя. Предполагаю что приложение собрано некорректно. Если нативно писать то это настраивается в Икскод и добавляются папки .lproj ( так описано на сайте эпл), а при expo build:ios не всё так ясно. Как можно решить данную проблему?

[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 0):

Для пермишенов можно указывать своё собственно описание, делается это в info plist файле, если используется expo то можно указать через его конфиг
https://docs.expo.dev/guides/permissions/#ios